# Pages icon is shown twice on Launchpad - One icon works, the second one loads

Tags: macos, pages, icon, launchpad

I just have installed Pages on my macOS Sierra Macbook Pro.
For some reason, this is what I see on the Launchpad:
[image]

The regular icon works, but the one who has the loading bar doesn't work.
I'm able to open the program using the regular icon, not the loading one. When I'm pressing Option key, the X button appears only above the loading icon, and when I'm trying to delete it using the X button, nothing happens. Over the regular icon, there is no X button at all.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Did you try restarting?

Comment: You're welcome! I've never seen that before, so it may just be a 1-time thing.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the solution was just to restart the laptop